# Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined -> while creating local DB Using ionic sqlite

Tags: ionic3

It is throwing error at line  `this.sqlite.create` saying

> ```
> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
> at get (vendor.js:61414)
> at getPlugin (vendor.js:61446)
> at checkAvailability (vendor.js:74896)
> at vendor.js:78283
> at SQLite.create (vendor.js:78288)
> at new DatabaseProvider (main.js:80)
> at _createClass (vendor.js:11620)
> at _createProviderInstance$1 (vendor.js:11592)
> at resolveNgModuleDep (vendor.js:11577)
> at NgModuleRef_.get (vendor.js:12814)
> at c (polyfills.js:3)
> at c (polyfills.js:3)
> at polyfills.js:3
> ```

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite/ngx';

@Injectable()
export class DatabaseProvider {

  private db: SQLiteObject;
  private isOpen: boolean;


  constructor(
    private http: HttpClientModule,
    private sqlite: SQLite,

  ) {
      this.sqlite.create({
        name:'data.db',
        location:'default'
      })
      .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {     
        this.db = db;
        db.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ticketdetails (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, movie text, showtime TEXT)", []);
        this.isOpen = true;      
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
    }


  insertTicketDetails(from: string, to:string, fare:number,route_number:String){
    return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
      let sql = "INSERT INTO ticketdetails (movie,showtime) VALUES (?,?)";
      this.db.executeSql(sql, [`enter code here`movie,showtime]).then((data) =>{
        resolve(data);
      }, (error) => {
        reject(error);
      });
    });
  }


}
```

Comment: Are you testing the app in browser?

Comment: no i am testing in the mobile only

Comment: try putting the code in `ionViewDidLoad()` instead of `constructor()`

Comment: Hi it is working fine but again its showing some error:TypeError: Cannot read property 'executeSql' of undefined
    at main.js:983
    at new t (polyfills.js:3)
    at DatabaseProvider.webpackJsonp.324.DatabaseProvider.insertTicketDetails (main.js:981)...........